# how do i grab push ID from database firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

how do i grab the `PUSH ID` generated from firebase `push` method. I need to store this `key` in my `App.js` file for `queries` in the future. im not sure how to grab this key when the user is already logged in. I posted a pic of what im reffering to, to clarify

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the pushid based on the email provided, then try the following:

```
firebase.database().ref().child("users").orderByChild("email").equalTo(yourEmail).on("value", function (snapshot) {
 snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
  var randomKey=childSnapshot.key;
  });
});
```

The snapshot is at the node `users` then you loop inside the keys and retrieve them using the `key` property

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#key

Comment: ok so this spits out all the keys, which is good, but now how do i know which key belongs to which user based off email?

Comment: then do `firebase.database().ref().child("users").orderByChild("email").equalTo(yourEmail).on("value", function (snapshot) {`

Comment: please update the answer to reflect this & you've got it!!!! THANK YOU SO MUCH!! WAS SUCH A HEADACHE!!